# Does anyone else get annoyed by the inbox for responses on your current page?

Tags: discussion, global-inbox

Possibly this is just a problem of mine<sup>1</sup> but fairly often I have answered a question and are in the process of refining my answer or am simply refreshing the page when I get a notification telling me that there is a new comment on my answer.

This annoys me slightly as my browser usually auto-scrolls me to my last point on the page on a refresh and I have already *seen* the comment before I find the notification. Normally I put up with this as I figure that there are use cases for the notification on the same page (e.g. responses to multiple comments that may be earlier/later on the page) and it doesn't really hurt anyone.

That is, until today when I managed to refresh a page, notice a comment and post a response, only to get a notification in my inbox upon *leaving the page to find another question*. I then followed the link thinking "Huh, he responded quickly" only to find that I had not only already seen it, but had already responded!

"This is the last straw that broke the unicorn's back" I said, and came here to rant about it.

Of course, I don't know if there's anything that can be done - really it's just a race condition where I refreshed in between when my inbox is updated and when the question itself is updated.

Does anyone else get annoyed by the inbox sometimes?

<sub><sup>1</sup> I compulsively mark all email as 'read' even if I don't plan on ever reading it, because I dislike having a notification that isn't dealt with.</sub>

Comment: [my bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578215/java-generics-question-regarding-type-capture-and-generated-inference-using-gene/7578415#comment9191815_7578415)

Comment: @KublaiKhan Are you stalking me? It's okay if you are, I'm just wondering.

Comment: Haha don't flatter yourself, I just happened to hit up meta at the right time :) *Now why aren't you returning my calls?*

Comment: I get annoyed when the inbox shows stuff I've already seen.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I can't say that I've been annoyed by that. It does seem like the top banner can be slightly out of sync sometimes, but on the whole it is farily well-behaved. Eventually, I would like to see that top banner updating in real-time though.

Comment: Real-time updates would be awesome, if only because then I wouldn't need to refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

I have the "problem" as well, at least a bit.

I'm slightly annoyed, but I don't think there's an easy solution:

The problem is that just because you've opened a page that contains the new response **doesn't** mean that you've seen the new response. For example, you might be reading a different answer or you might be in the process of editing your answer and the comment is 1 page below the lower border of your browser.

And if SO wrongly decides that you've seen that answer, then suddenly "ugh, why do I get notified for what I already saw?" turns into "Oh no! Why didn't the gods of SO notify me of this immensely interesting comment that I didn't see 3 months ago?".

**Edit:** *however*, if SO realizes that I actually *answered* the comment (*and* the comment was shown to me *before* I started typing the answer*) *then* it could assume that I've read it.

Comment: "To err is human. To err on the side of caution is good design."